# Compile problem in robot_model (catkin_package)

Tags: ros, robot-model, catkin-package, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

When I try to compile the robot_model it shows that:
"
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:6 (catkin_package):
Unknown CMake command "catkin_package".
"

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 & ROS Fuerte.

Can someone tell me how to solve the problem?

Thank you very much.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/48174/compile-problem-in-robot_model-(catkin_package)/) by [TsaiFinland](https://answers.ros.org/users/3582/tsaifinland/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2012-11-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I guess you are trying to compile a Groovy package in Fuerte. The build system changed a lot so this will certainly not work. Don't use the default branch but the robot_model-1.8 branch which is also used for building the Fuerte Debian package.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-11-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TsaiFinland](https://answers.ros.org/users/3582/tsaifinland/) on 2012-11-12**:
Thank you. Solved  by:
hg clone https://kforge.ros.org/robotmodel/robot_model -r robot_model-1.8.0